# Samba share - windows 7 no permission to share

Tags: samba, fedora, share

I just have installed Fedora 15. Connected my external HDD by USB and configured fstab. Next I installed samba and I'm trying to share this disk over my local network. I see my server and directory but I can not access it with my Windows 7.

Here is my testparm:

```
[global]
        workgroup = FAMILIA
        server string = Serwer ECHO
        security = SHARE
        log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
        max log size = 50
        load printers = No
        guest ok = Yes
        cups options = raw

[multimedia]
        comment = Dysk z multimediami
        path = /mnt/multimedia
        force user = nobody
        force group = marverix
        read only = No
        create mask = 0777
```

User nobody is added to marverix group. And this group have even permission 0777 to /mnt/multimedia.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

"force user" and "force group" are pointless in this regard, unless you have non-anonymous users connecting too.

"cups options = raw" also shouldn't be relevant since you have printers disabled.

Have you tried setting "guest account = nobody" in [global] ?

Comment: yes I tried and nothing...